# How to decompres array of char in c

Tags: c, pointers

I need to create function:

```
char * decompress(const char * src) {
}
```

input to this function is some string:

```
Hello world! -> Hello world!

Hel2o world!10" -> Hello world!!!!!!!!!!
```

as you can see if there is some number it repeat previous char this number times. I am java programmer but now I need to solve this in c;

I have now this. It just print I hope right value but I dont know how to assign it to return pointer

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <assert.h>

char * decompress(const char * src) {
    int max = 0;
    int pom = 1;

    char *vysledek = "";
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(src); i++) {
        max = 0;
        pom = 1;

        while (isdigit(src[i])) {
            int digit = (src[i] - '0');
            max = max * 10 + digit;
            i++;
            pom++;
        }

        if (max == 0) {
            max = 1;
        }

        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < max; j++) {
            printf("%c", src[i - pom]);
        }
    }

    return vysledek;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv []) {

    decompress("Hel2o world!10");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If the rest of your code works you need to make small changes: allocate memory to your output string and then simply add the characters to it. However, the question remains exactly how much memory you should allocate to your string. You can either go with a static value (which will work to all lengths up to it), approximate, or run a separate loop to first figure out how much space you need. Another option would be to dynamically allocate some amount of memory and then allocate twice the size if it's filled up and copy the contents over.

Comment: You have UB in your code as in the first iteration of the outer `for` loop,the inner `for` loop print `src[-1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned that you are a Java programmer, you should look into how C memory assignment (in this case especially strings) work:

```
char *vysledek = "";
```

In Java, this would create a string object, where you can simply add characters at your will. In C, however, this will basically create an array of `char[1]`, containing `'\0'` (string termination character).

Since - like Java's arrays - you can't (shouldn't) write outside of an array's boundaries, you could store one character in this array, which is of not sufficient memory for your function.

You can find out how much memory you will have to allocate by iterating over the input first (as Nit has mentioned in his comment). Then you can `malloc` the necessary memory for your output pointer:

```
vysledek = malloc (<output string length>);
```

Now that you have allocated enough memory, you can write your output into this array, so instead of

```
printf("%c", src[i - pom]);
```

you can now write:

```
vysledek[vysledek_counter++] = src[i - pom];
```

and return the pointer.

Please note that you *should* free the returned value after you're done using it, even if it's at the end of your main method, which should look something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv []) {
    char *output;

    output = decompress("Hel2o world!10");
    printf("%s\n", output);
    free(output);

    return 0;
}
```

One additional note to add: Your code will fail if it encounters a non-terminated string (that is, there is no `'\0'` character to indicate the string's end). To counter this, pass an additional string-length parameter (you'll have to set the `'\0'` character yourself in the returned `char` array, and reserve one additional byte of memory for this pointer). It also has undefined behaviour (as Cool Guy has pointed out) on its first iteration, as `pom` is always at least 1, resulting in `i - pom`, therefore trying to access `src[-1]`.

Comment: I am still confused about pointer. I tried your example but it still doesnt work. When I printf("%c\n", vysledek[0]); it return nothing 
    printf("%c\n", vysledek[1]); return H (Why) and printf("%s\n", vysledek); return also nothing why

Comment: I think in this case the confusion stems from strings in C:
Whenever a "\0" character is encountered, most functions handling a string (including printf) will stop processing the string, since there is no way to tell the length of an array (and therefore of a string). I've edited my answer, but the problem you're facing right now is: When your loop starts, the first character in `vysledek` is set to `src[-1]`; this can set the first character to `'\0'`, therefore appearing as an empty string. (Note: `'\0' == 0`, therefore `printf("%d", vysledek[0]);` will print out 0)

Comment: A few other errors: After reading a number, you basically skip a character without writing it to the target array. (when your `isdigit` loop finishes, it points to - for example - 'o', reads 'l' two times into the target array (now 3 'l' exist in the array, because the first one was read into the array before detecting any numbers), and increases the counter `i` again without reading in 'o'.